# how to warn user if it is used a strange character in eval operation

Tags: php

```
$op=$_POST['param'];
$statement=eval("return ($op);");
```

in 'param', if there is a strange character such letter 'jfsdf' or something else the eval function does not work.  How can I solve this problem?

eval function works only well defined entries such as '54+4*3' on the other hand if it is used entries such '6p+87+4' it gives an parse error. Is there any way to warn user in order to enter a well defined statement

Comment: Quoting the string would be a start! And then doing an `addslashes()`. That should be enough.

Comment: This looks like a cross-site scripting nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: eval function works only well defined entries such as '54+4*3' on the other hand if it is used entries such '6p+87+4' it gives an parse error. Is there any way to warn user in order to enter a well defined statement

Comment: There is absolutely no way you should ever pass user-submitted data into an `eval` call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP EVAL - Fixing an Insecurity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843950/php-eval-fixing-an-insecurity)

Comment: @meagar: As long as it isn't being stored, and sent to other users, any evil JS would only affect that user. Though variable scope should be given due consideration.

Comment: ...wait, is this about PHP or JS? Maybe I'm missing a point here.

Comment: @amnotiam yes, but it can affect that user in nasty ways that they do not intend. Eg cookie stealing.

Comment: @amnotiam The code posted is PHP. This is not about JS-injection, it's about server-side use of `eval` on user-submitted data.

Comment: @meagar: Ah, thought maybe I was missing something. Thanks.

Comment: @ddlshack: I suppose... but wouldn't it just be the user's data for the local site? The user has access to that cookie info irrespective of `eval`. Again, maybe I've missed the point.

Comment: Yeah but other people can trick you into visiting those pages which send your cookie data to their server. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Non-persistent

Comment: @ddlshack: Thanks for the link. I really need to study up on this type of activity.

Comment: @ddlshack You're over-thinking the security issues present in server-side eval of untrusted data. The concern has nothing to do with cookies. Somebody can pass the string `"; system('rm -rf /')"` to recursively delete all data on your machine. Or `"; passthru('cat /etc/passwd')"` to read the contents of your password database. You're giving somebody the ability to execute arbitrary shell commands on your server, essentially the worst vulnerability there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, depending on what you mean by "strange" character, you should implement function that verifies the string coming from outside.

```
$allowed_chars = array('function', 'this' ); //..add desirable ones

function is_alloved_char($char){
 return in_array($char, $allowed_chars);
}
```

RegEx is great for this when You Do except some performance down.

In your situation `str_pos()` is great enough to match undesirable chars.

so, your another function should be similar to:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param string
 * @return TRUE on success, FALSE otherwise
 */
function is_really_safe($char){
  global $allowed_chars; //just make this array visible here
 foreach ($allowed_chars as $allowed_char){
   if ( str_pos($allowed_char, $char) ){
     return false;
   }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Also, be VERY VERY careful with eval()
If you use this function in product, then you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about evaluation a constrained math expression, then the lazy option would be to use a pattern assertion prior evaluating. This one's also easier as it returns you the expression result implicitly:

```
$result = preg_replace('#^\s*\d+([-+*/%]\s*\d+\s*)*$#e', '$0', $input);
```

Would need something more complex if you wanted to assert `(..)` parens are correctly structured as well.

If it doesn't match, it will return the original input string. Check that for generating a warning.